# fetching Id for matching row - any performance difference between two approaches?

Tags: c#, linq

I have method that returns `Guid?`. I come across two ways to fetch `matching Id from table`.

> 1- Which one is the preferred way or its just personnel preference?
>   2- Any performance difference?

```
private Guid? findCustomerId(string customerNo)
{
    // 1st way
    return _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == customerNo).Id;

    // 2nd way
    return _context.Customers.Where(x => x.Code == customerNo).Select(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Comment: Best suggestion is to check the generated sql and compare. Might even be the same

Comment: There are tools for inspecting the generated SQL -- such as the Entity Framework Profiler. I would expect both statements to generate the same SQL, but would be interested to see the output.

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Profiler? never heard about Entity Profiler !

Comment: I did profiling (SQL Profiler) .. the result says method 2 is better.

Comment: Added to my question. have a look and let me know what you seems better?

Comment: Both those methods seem susceptible to a Null Reference Exception if the customerNo isn't found, FYI.

Comment: @Graham, 1st is susceptible to null. I think not second one ! but thats good point.. how you will avoid null exception than?

Comment: The Where().Select().FirstOrDefault approach returns a default Guid (but not a null one). I'd do something like `Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == custNo)?.Id ?? null` if you want to return the nullable Guid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches generate the same sql but to one difference - **which columns to return** of that one selected row:

```
// 1st way - Returns entire record to memory and then you decide to take just ID
return _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == customerNo).Id;

// 2nd way - Returns just the column of ID to memory
return _context.Customers.Where(x => x.Code == customerNo).Select(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you strip the columns from the generated sql you can see that they are doing the same.

```
//Approach 1:
SELECT [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) *
       FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
       WHERE ([Extent1].[Code] = @p__linq__0) 
       OR (([Extent1].[Code] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
    )  AS [Limit1]



//Approach 2:
SELECT TOP (1) *    
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Code] = @p__linq__0) 
OR (([Extent1].[Code] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
```

1. Both queries retrieve `TOP (1)` records
2. `WHERE` clauses are the same
3. The nested `SELECT` in the first approach has no performance influence

---

If you don't have any cricital performance problems (or if your colums contain huge fields of data) caused by retrieving the entire record then go for readability - and the first way is more readable in my opinion

Comment: are you sure both generate same SQL? I did profiling and found both generate different sql. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Performance is concern. So i would go 2nd approach. I don't want to return all columns when i don't need of them.The nested SELECT in the first approach has no performance influence OR has minimal performance influence. I think minimal

Comment: @simbada - How big is each record? In bytes?

Comment: @simbada - about the nested select - it is something to check carefully but from my experience it has no influence